# Flexbox with percent width but fixed margins

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to switch from a CSS grid framework to a flex layout (because of different items height, and flexbox handles that very nicely).

So, this is what I did: http://jsfiddle.net/c3FL2/

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #9999FF;
}
.g {
    background: #FF9999;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 15px;
}
.grid-33 {
    width: 33.3333%;
}
.grid-50 {
    width: 50%;
}
.grid-66 {
    width: 66.6666%;
}
.grid-100 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

My question is: how can i add a margin between flex items? I want exactly 15px, not a percentage. If I add that, it breaks the layout because of too much width. Padding is not a solution because I want a border outside elements.

The solution doesn't have to be compatible with old browser, just the latest ones since this will be running on a controlled environment.

Edit: If needed, the HTML can be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try : `background-clip` and `box-shadow` and `transparent` `border`s: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c3FL2/2/)**

```
    .g {
        background: #FF9999;
        border: 8px solid transparent;/* you may tune individually border-size to get your 15px */
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px red;/* this will fake your border if set with out blur */
        background-clip:padding-box;/* do not show bgcolor under borders */
        border-radius: 15px;/* increase value so it has effect deeper seen  on inset box-shadow */
        padding: 15px;
    }
```

Comment: Is this really the only solution? Seems like a sort of hack :( if you can alter the html and add for example another div with 100% height and apply the border there? Could it work?

Comment: @JohnKiller then in that case, you need to use box-sizing too, and you already do, so it should be fine. I do not see a hack, there is no way to draw twice the border and margin cannot be included in width calculation as padding does. I do not really see other possibilities unless to relay on javascript to set width and margin on the fly. height:100%, do you mean this http://jsfiddle.net/c3FL2/3/

Comment: no, but i think i got it working the way i want. thanks aniway

Answer (score 6):

The "easiest" way to do this is to use calc(). (It would of course be easier if you didn't have to solve for IE quirks to get there, but the end result is very straightforward.) Your code would look like this:

```
.container {
  padding: 15px 15px 0 0;
}
.g {
  margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
}
.grid-33 {
  with: calc(33.3333% - 15px);
}
.grid-50 {
  width: calc(50% - 15px);
}
.grid-66 {
  width: calc(66.6666% - 15px);
}
.grid-100 {
  width: calc(100% - 15px); // needed for IE10
}
```

The reason for using `width` is because IE10-11 aren't great fans of `calc` being used together with `flex`. In this case it's a `box-sizing: border-box` [issue](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#7-flex-basis-doesnt-account-for-box-sizingborder-box). This example is cross-browser compatible with IE10+.

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/sambible/pen/eZxQyP)

(To see vendor prefixes, click "View Compiled" in CSS.)

Answer (score 0):

Only tested this in chrome but seems to work

try changing the styles to this:

```
.g {
    //add margin style
    margin:15px;
}
.grid-33 {
    flex: 1 1 33.3333%;
}
.grid-50 {
    flex: 1 1 50%;
}
.grid-66 {
    flex: 1 1 66.6666%;
}
.grid-100 {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is old, I had a similar problem. I achieved the margins by adding an extra element and moving the styling to that element. This seems quite robust, `calc()` no matter how well supported doesn't feel neat enough.

```
.padder {
  background: #FF9999;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
  display:flex;
}
```

Placing `display:flex` on the extra element ensures its contents fill the space within.

http://jsfiddle.net/c3FL2/28/